# Prettier: Add space between function and parenthesis

Tags: prettier

In VSCode, each time I save a JS file, **Prettier** removes the space between the function keyword and its parenthesis.

It changes this:

```
function (parameter)
```

To this:

```
function(parameter)
```

But I want to keep the space.

Some people are suggesting adding this rule to VSCode setting:

```
"prettier.spaceBeforeFunctionParen": true
```

But apparently this rule doesn't exist any more.

How can I force a space between function and parenthesis in Prettier?

Comment: As i understand, there's so much argue about this rule, i just disabled this rule in eslint.

Comment: @Alexander Kim, which rule did you disable in eslint?

Answer (score 11):

in setting.json add

```
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    }
```

after, when you save your work, eslint fix your error like space before function parenthese.

Comment: For me I also had to set  `"editor.formatOnSave": false` it was overwriting what prettier did on save.

Answer (score 5):

Interestingly, I get the opposite behavior.

I have VSCode set up to use my `.prettierrc` config file. But when I set VSCode to "Format on Save", a space gets added before my function parens, even when I have this set to false in .prettierrc: `“spaceBeforeFunctionParen": false`.

This function signature:

```
const myFunction = function(datevalue) {
```

... always changes to:

```
const myFunction = function (datevalue) {
```

I can't find a way to avoid this with prettier. So, in part because the extraneous space looks peculiar to me, I now pretty much always just use arrow functions instead:

```
const myFunction = (datevalue) => {
```

Answer (score -2):

To solve that issue you had to set the config on your **settings.js**:

```
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": false,
  "editor.formatOnType": false
}
```

or go to the vscode settings **"File => Preferences => settings"** search for **onSave** and unchecked the **"Format On Save"** check box.